# Add baked texture to render (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking

Hi I'm having a problem with baking textures. I have done one but I don't know how to add this texture to an object to speed up rendering. The texture is visible in Viewport Shading: Texture. But rendering is as slow as before. Is it possible to turn off shadows and other things for only this object with baked texture?

Comment: Could you post a .blend file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wan't to do is use an emission shade-less material:

In the material node editor, use a setup like this (The UV map is optional) It is important to keep the strength of the emission node down to 1

[image]

**If everything in your scene is baked, use this to cut render times:**

You can also avoid a-lot of extra calculations by cutting down on the samples and light bounces. You can set all of these values to 1:

[image]

Comment: You need to select the baked texture in the image texture node.

Answer (score 4):

**Once you have the texture baked you need to assign it as an emission material to the object.**

This is pretty simple:

1. Go to the node editor
2. Disconnect any nodes you have plugged into the *surface* socket on the *material output* node (you needn't delete them).
3. Add an *emission* shader and an *image texture* node.
4. Select the baked texture on the image texture node and plug it into the color input of the emission shader and plug the emission shader into the surface output.  Make sure the *strength* of the emission shader is 1.00.

Note that if the camera is animated, baked glossy sharers will not look right.

For further reference, see Andrew Price's [Introduction to Baking in Cycles](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles/#.VHyc95UtDX4).